# Prevent tomcat to save uploaded file

Tags: java, tomcat, httprequest

I am working on scan the uploaded file for virus. I get the inputstream from the http request and send it to scan engine. Looks before this step, tomcat already save a tmp file upload_46e2cad7_4e1b_4fe5_83c7_39dca4a77763_00000000.tmp in the work/Catelinna/host/ directory. Can I prevent tomcat from doing that before I scan the uploaded file?

Comment: `@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE)` may be able to do it. See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets011.htm